# Render ByteBuffer as an image in a Swing application

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I have a frame of video data in a direct `ByteBuffer`. What is the optimal way to render this as an image in a Swing component?

By "optimal", I mean with as few buffer copies as possible.

My naive implementation uses a `JPanel` that draws a `BufferedImage`. This component is referenced by `imagePane` in the code fragment below:

```
private final int[] array = new int[width*height];

private BufferedImage image; // Contained by imagePane

public void render(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
    IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
    intBuffer.get(array);
    image.getWritableRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, array);
    imagePane.repaint();
}
```

This implementation, for every video frame, gets an `IntBuffer` from the `ByteBuffer`, and copies the whole thing into an `int[]` - this is then written into the `BufferedImage` raster and the component repainted.

This works well enough, even for full-screen HD video, but is there a way to do this with less buffer copying?

JavaFX has a `WritableImage` with a `PixelWriter` that can accept the `ByteBuffer` directly as a parameter, but I am looking for something that works as well as possible with Swing/Java2D.

Comment: I'm not an expert on image formats, but it seems to me that without specifying an image format, a ByteBuffer alone would not be enough to create an image

Comment: The image format is under my control - for the sake of argument assume RGBA with an unused alpha channel. Please bear in mind the code I have works and renders the image correctly, so the image format is not the issue here (unless I suppose I could use a more efficient format).

Comment: If the main reason for avoiding the copies is to increase the performance: Note that copying a whole chunk of memory is fast, and it's unlinkely to introduce a prohibitively large overhead. Additionally, when the data is copied, the image can be *trackable* (aka *managed*), and it can be held in VRAM and painted efficiently. Although it is possible to create a `BufferedImage` directly from a `ByteBuffer` (as `IntBuffer`), painting such an image may be slow. (Websearch: `directbufferedimage` and similar terms).